# How to print all the jasper report with in one PDF with jasperreports-5.6.0

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am using jasper report version jasperreports-5.6.0. I can successfully print jasper reports in separate pdf. now I want to print all of them with in one pdf. I have also tried to use JRExporter. But my netbeans can't find the documentation of it.here is my code.

```
enter code here
 public void printAllData(ArrayList printableIds){
     Iterator itr=printableIds.iterator();
     List<JasperPrint> jprintlist = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
     try{
         JasperReport jasperReport =   JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\Documents\\New Folder\\JahangirWorkshop\\report3.jrxml");
      Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

      while(itr.hasNext()){     
            parameters.put("PADNUMBER",itr.next()); 
             JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);
             printlist.add(jasperPrint);
             jprintlist.add(jasperPrint);
             JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
            // JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

      } 
       JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

 }catch(Exception ex){
 }
}
```